# Put timestamp with awk at the beginning of a file each time

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to put timestamp at the beginning of a file each time I call the awk command

I have a script with some commands and I want when I run a command to put that event to a log file with timestamp
but I want that line to be at the begin of the log file each time.

with echo I can do it but the it goes at the end of file

```
echo "$(date +%d/%m/%Y) - $(date +%T)" ' - Script event 1' >> log.txt
```

I try with awk but I can't print date-time

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print "$(date +%d/%m/%Y) - $(date +%T) - Script event 1"}{print}' log.txt
```

So I want something like that

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print "$(date +%d/%m/%Y) - $(date +%T) - Script event 1"}{print}' log.txt
(......
some commands
......)
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print "$(date +%d/%m/%Y) - $(date +%T) - Script event 2"}{print}' log.txt
(......
some commands
......)
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print "$(date +%d/%m/%Y) - $(date +%T) - Script event 3"}{print}' log.txt
```

and my output log.txt to be

```
01/01/2021 - 16:50:05 - Script event 3
01/01/2021 - 16:52:15 - Script event 2
01/01/2021 - 16:54:25 - Script event 1
```

Comment: Doest this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224969/current-date-in-awk answer your question?

Comment: I encourage you to use the standardized `%Y-%m-%d` date format -- it is unambiguous, plus it sorts the same chronologically and lexically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU awk for `-i inplace` and time functions, use `strftime()` to add timestamp at the starting of file.

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print strftime("%d/%m/%Y - %T") " - Script event 1"}{print}' log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

awk doesn't have the shell's command substitution syntax.

To capture the output of an external command, you use an awk pipe with `getline`

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {
  cmd = "date \"+%F %T\""
  cmd | getline timestamp
  close(cmd)
  print ">>", timestamp, "<<"
}'
```

```
>> 2021-07-17 09:36:06 <<
```

or, for reading multiple lines from an external command, a while loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    cmd = "seq 5"
    while ((cmd | getline line) > 0) {
        print ">>", line, "<<"
    }
    close(cmd)
}'
```

```
>> 1 <<
>> 2 <<
>> 3 <<
>> 4 <<
>> 5 <<
```

---

Of course, with GNU awk, use the [builtin time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)